# Discrete-time martingale

Tags: probability

I am self-learning SDE from the book, Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales, 2nd ed., by Rogers and Williams. There is one proof that puzzles me. It is the proof of Theorem 59.6.

The setting is as follows:

> Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras. let $\xi$ be $L^1(\Omega)$ and $\xi_n = E(\xi | \mathcal{F}_n)$. Let $T$ be a stopping time and define $\eta = E(\xi | \mathcal{F}_T)$.

Then the book says the following holds:

> $E(\eta|\mathcal{F}_n) = \xi_{n \wedge T}$ a.s. for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How does one prove this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z_n:=\mathsf{E}[\eta\mid \mathcal{F}_n]$. Then since $Z_n$ and $\xi_{n\wedge T}$ are UI martingales converging a.s. to $\xi_T$, by Theorem 50.1,
$$
Z_n=\mathsf{E}[\xi_T\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\xi_{n\wedge T} \quad\text{a.s.}
$$

Comment: Ah, yes, Theorem 50.1, that is what I missed. Thank you very much!